# How do I put a csv into an external table in SNowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, external-tables

I have a staged file and I am trying to query the first line/row of it because it contains the column headers of the file. Is there a way I can create an external table using this file so that I can query the first line?

I am able to query the staged file using

```
SELECT a.$1
FROM @my_stage (FILE_FORMAT=>'my_file_format',PATTERN=>'my_file_path') a
```

and then to create the table I tried doing

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE MY_FILE_TABLE
    WITH
        LOCATION='my_file_path'
        FILE_FORMAT = my_file_format;
```

Comment: If the goal is to have clean syntax to read the header, would defining the query as a view meet your requirements? Defining it as an external table may be overkill depending on the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Reading Headers from CSV is not supported however this answer from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65777710/how-to-get-the-header-names-of-a-staged-csv-file-on-snowflake) gives a workaround.